# How do I inspect an element under another element in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I got to this complicated page, and a modal is in my way. I want to inspect an element that's obscured. I know I could walk the document tree in the elements tab, but is there some sort of "select under" option in Chrome?

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 4em;
  background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
}

.modal-border {
  border: 4px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<p>this text element is what I want to inspect</p>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-border">
    This modal is blocking me from inspecting what's underneath it
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you know the name of the element or the content it should display, you can open the inspector and in the HTML tree, use `ctrl-f` or `cmd-f` to find the element you are looking for. Otherwise, your answer is the way I work, removing an element and then ctrl-z or walking the tree which is sometimes painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@xmanfly's solution didn't work for me. But I did figure out that I can add a css property to the modal to make it temporarily go away.

```
display: none;
```

Another option is to delete the modal element, but in this case I didn't want to. Either way I can inspect element, then undo (Ctrl-Z or Command-Z) to get the modal to show up after I inspect the target element.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `aria-hidden="true"` after `<div class="modal"`, so then it would look like `<div class="modal" aria-hidden="true">`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to hide the obscuring element. First start out by inspecting the element that is covering the element you actually want to inspect. Then in the chrome elements tab, right click on that element and click hide. Now you can inspect that same area and inspect the element underneath. When you're done you can then unhide the covering element.

However, in some cases the above may not work, such as when an element has the style `visibility: visible !important;`. In that case you'll need to add the inline style `display: none` to override.